# How do I add a second link to this java script radio selection?

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out how to insert the second link. I'd like each radio button to direct to a different link.

```js
<script>
    function myFunction() {
   
        if(document.getElementById('slide1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://www.nationsprint.com/clients/ccpopv2/catalog.cgi";
            
        
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" >


<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink">MyLink</a>
```

Comment: ...use the same code with the element ID `slide2`? Or am I not understanding the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add multiple `href`s to one element. If I understand you correctly, you want to change `href` based on selected radio input. Here it is:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('slide1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://www.nationsprint.com/clients/ccpopv2/catalog.cgi"; 
  } else if (document.getElementById('slide2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('myLink').href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
  }
  
  alert("Current 'href' is: " + document.getElementById('myLink').href);
}
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" >

<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink">MyLink</a>
```

Comment: @CapCity not all websites can be opened from SO snipped, but it should work on regular webpage. I have changed the second href to SO URL, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons support different values. You can use this to set them the url you want them to redirect to.

```
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" value="https://www.nationsprint.com/clients/ccpopv2/catalog.cgi">
```

Then, you can use [document.querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) to get the selected radio.

```
var link = document.querySelector('input[name="slider"]:checked').value
```

Here's a snippet showing how it works:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var link = document.querySelector('input[name="slider"]:checked').value
    document.getElementById('myLink').href = link;
}
```

```html
<input checked="checked" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" value="https://stackoverflow.com/">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" value="https://www.nationsprint.com/clients/ccpopv2/catalog.cgi">

<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink">MyLink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set  the  href as 'javascript:void(0)',to prevent the  tag's default action.

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var slide1=document.getElementById('slide1');
        var slide2=document.getElementById('slide2');
        var myLink=document.getElementById('myLink');
        if(slide1.checked) {
            myLink.href = "https://www.nationsprint.com/clients/ccpopv2/catalog.cgi";
        }
            
        if(slide2.checked) {
            myLink.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
        }
    }
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" >


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink" >MyLink</a>
```

Comment: this doesn't solve going to another page if you select the other radio input